# How to change id of image using kineticjs

Tags: javascript, image, kineticjs

First i create an image with id:image1.then i want to change the id image1 into image2 and create new image with the id:image1...I tried but it is not working.can anyone help me?

```
            var image = new Kinetic.Image({
                    name: data,
                    id: "image1",
                    x: stage.getWidth()*0.5-20,
                    y: stage.getHeight()*0.5-125,
                    width:20,
                    height:250,
                    image: theImage,
                    draggable: false
                });
         image.setId("image2");
         var image = new Kinetic.Image({
                        name: data,
                        id: "image1",
                        x: stage.getWidth()*0.5-200,
                        y: stage.getHeight()*0.5-125,
                        width:20,
                        height:250,
                        image: theImage,
                        draggable: false
             });
```

Comment: you shouldn't really be changing id's dynamically, you'd be better off changing a class on the images.

Comment: @atmd I have tried with the attribute name. but it's not working...

Comment: Yeah name is also something you wouldnt really change, you'd be better of with either a class document.getElementById(someElement).className OR assigning data to the element (i.e. data-active / data-image='1')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      var kk=stage.find("#image1")[0];
      kk.setId("image2");
```